# Will Apple Reject This?

Tags: xcode, navigation, toolbar, tabbarcontroller

Everyone.

I have never seen double toolbars like this before in an app, but I like it. Those I have showed it to like it. However, because I have never seen it in an app like this, do you think Apple will reject it?

[Example](http://s28.postimg.org/z2bzkdv71/Screen_Shot_2015_08_08_at_12_23_58_PM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from Apples website:

> **Substandard User Interface**
>
> Apple places a high value on clean, refined, and user-friendly interfaces. Make sure your UI meets these requirements by planning your design carefully and following our design guides and [UI Design Dos and Don'ts.](https://developer.apple.com/design/tips/)

In my eyes it looks very clean and simple. I don't think it'll be a rejection reason if you submit something with the image you show us.

Apples own example of something that would be rejected because of its UI looks like this:
[image]